# WebView inside Unity 3D UWP Application?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webview, uwp

well I want to show a generated .HTML file inside the UWP app developet by Unity3D. I tried lots of packages and always found a dead end. Is there any package or asset that provides this feature (for free?) out of the box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is one asset that will work with UWP. It's called PowerUI https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/powerui-html-css-10374 It's not actually a browser, but it can generate html pages. It can be used as a webbrowser, but it doesn't have every feature, so they don't 'sell' it as a browser.